# Google Docs: Script Project is not editable for anyone

Tags: google-drive, sharing, google-apps-script

I created a new Script Project in Google Docs with the following sharing settings:
"Anyone who has the link can access. No sign-in required." -
"Edit access: Allow anyone to edit (no sign-in required)" is activated.
The sharing settings overview says: "Anyone who has the link can edit".

However, this doesn't work for me. If I'm logged out, I have no access to the document at all. Users with a Google-Account are able to view/edit the project.

Where is the problem?

**edit:**
The same settings within a normal Google Document actually work as they should.